# Pretty Print cURL output (both JSON & XML) in Dos

Tags: curl

Is it possible to pretty print cURL output (both JSON & XML) in Dos.
I tried to search this, but options are available for Unix types systems only.

Thanks for your answers.

RSN

Comment: Are you printing response from sfdc here?

Comment: Yes. I am printing command from SFDC.
I am using cURL tool to send HTTP requests.

Comment: -H "Accept: application/xml"
The response format is decided by Accept parameter and hence when use Accept as application/xml then the response will be in XML

By default Accept header for request is application/json

Comment: I guess this is more relevant for stackoverflow

Comment: Hi Mohith, i was asking about getting pretty print format as the output of cURL is very difficult to read.
I guess, you are right. I will post this question in Stackoverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) It's CURL-like, open source, multi-platform (DOS, Win, Mac), it offers several prettify options - format, color etc.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, Yes you were right. Its better to go with Httpie. There is also one more chrome extension, Postman ReST client, that can be used.